# Git not found in docker container

Tags: git, docker, apt

My Dockefile is based on python-bullseye:3.9 image.
The line of installing git:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget unzip vim git
```

Build result:

```
...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7) ...
Setting up perl (5.32.1-4+deb11u2) ...
Setting up xauth (1:1.1-1) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17029-1) ...
Setting up git (1:2.30.2-1+deb11u2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u2) ...
...
```

Didn't see error during the installation.
However after the image is deployed to K8s pod,

```
# git --version
bash: git: command not found
```

```
# apt list git
Listing... Done
git/stable-security 1:2.30.2-1+deb11u2 amd64
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Based on the apt list seems it is installed.
Other packages such as vim all works perfectly.
If I manually run apt-get install git then everything just works fine.
Appreciate someone can give some clue where I can start to troubleshoot it.

Comment: if the command is not found, but it's installed you'd have to either call it b it's full path /usr/bin/git or add /usr/bin to the PATH environment variable

Comment: I need to understand why it happened this way and how to fix it in an automated way.

Comment: ```
# apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.30.2-1+deb11u2
  Version table:
     1:2.30.2-1+deb11u2 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:2.30.2-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```
Seems the installation actually failed but didn't throw any error.

Comment: Is wget installed? The problem could be with apt-update...

Comment: If you post the entire dockerfile, we may help... :)

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia thanks! Yes all other packages installed work alright. Sorry I can't share the whole file as the company policy. I changed a different base image and this issue seems gone. Anyway thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Hi @LiangHE, as a general rule, you can post a minimum reproducible example. You can strip all lines that do not influence the result and leave only the rest... In this case it would have probably been just the initial statement and the run you posted anyway.. 

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia the problem has been pinpointed that the base image I used wasn't a standard python bullseye image but our internal customized one. So to be honest I can't expect your help without showing the source of that base image which even I can't see it. Really appreciate your time looking at this. Will definitely consult with you if there is further question around it.